# Why does np.full raise a FutureWarning?

Tags: python, numpy, warnings

I ran the following code in python 2.7

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 25 2015, 12:33:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.10.0'
>>> np.full(1, 1, np.double)
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py:294: FutureWarning: in the future, full(..., 1) will return an array of dtype('int64')
  format(fill_value, array(fill_value).dtype), FutureWarning)
array([ 1.])
```

The FutureWarning might be helpful if I would not provide the `dtype`, but I don't understand why it also pops up in this simple case. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the warning chose a test that avoided a false warning when the value provided was already a `float64`. Unfortunately, they neglected your case where your explicitly-provided dtype also means that the warning is false.

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6382

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it on the numpy discussion list!